# DKMS fails to compile fglrx-driver on Debian Sid (using kernel-3.10-1)

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, build

My 'play' box (Debian Sid) just received an update for the kernel (3.10-1-amd64). Right after I installed appropriate linux headers I received an error from DKMS indicating failed build.

Below is the output from the **make.log**

```
DKMS make.log for fglrx-13.4 for kernel 3.10-1-amd64 (x86_64)
Thu Jul 18 21:15:47 EDT 2013
make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.10-1-amd64'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:476:0:
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/drm_proc.h: In function ‘FGLDRM_proc_init’:
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/drm_proc.h:98:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘create_proc_entry’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declarati$
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/drm_proc.h:98:19: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/drm_proc.h:105:12: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/drm_proc.h:112:7: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/drm_proc.h:124:6: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/drm_proc.h:125:6: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c: In function ‘firegl_proc_init’:
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:598:14: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:610:13: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:617:12: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:617:27: error: ‘read_proc_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:617:27: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:617:39: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:621:15: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:631:13: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:651:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:651:43: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:656:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:660:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:669:13: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:672:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:672:43: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:673:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:673:32: error: ‘write_proc_t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:673:45: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:674:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c: In function ‘KCL_EFI_IS_ENABLED’:
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:3091:5: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c: At top level:
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:523:1: warning: ‘firegl_debug_proc_read_wrap’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:528:12: warning: ‘firegl_debug_proc_write_wrap’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.c:546:12: warning: ‘firegl_major_proc_read’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[3]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build/firegl_public.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/fglrx/13.4/build] Error 2
make[1]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.10-1-amd64'
```

Are there any known 'fixes' for the this kernel version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this patch

https://github.com/kolasa/fglrx-13.101/commit/ae7de2751be17484bc98d82e1c1901e5d432e430

it works for me

linked from http://ati.cchtml.com/show_bug.cgi?id=847